# Haskell / Julius templates - can't splice variables

Tags: haskell, yesod, shakespeare-text, yesod-julius

I think there's something i don't understand about how splicing in julius works, none of the built in types will splice. The only way I can get code to compile is with rawJS.

For example:

```
import Prelude.Unicode
import Text.Julius

import Text.Shakespeare    -- not sure if this is needed
import Text.Shakespeare.Text    -- not sure if this is needed
...


test = renderJavascript $ jsCode (⊥)
  where
    yval = rawJS $ show (3 ∷ Int) -- works
    -- yval = show (3 ∷ Int) -- no instance of toJavascript
    -- yval = 3 ∷ Int -- no instance of toJavascript
    jsCode = [js|
      var y = #{yval};
      |]
```

FWIW I'm not using yesod, just the julius templating part of the library, but that shouldn't matter here I think.

If I try to splice the Int itself, I get an error like:

```
No instance for (ToJavascript Int)
  arising from a use of ‘toJavascript’
In the expression: toJavascript yval
In the first argument of ‘mconcat’, namely
  ‘[Javascript
      ((Data.Text.Internal.Builder.fromText . pack')
         "\n\
         \      var y = "),
    toJavascript yval,
    Javascript
      ((Data.Text.Internal.Builder.fromText . pack')
         ";\n\
         \      ")]’
In the expression:
  mconcat
    [Javascript
       ((Data.Text.Internal.Builder.fromText . pack')
          "\n\
          \      var y = "),
     toJavascript yval,
     Javascript
       ((Data.Text.Internal.Builder.fromText . pack')
          ";\n\
          \      ")]
```

Comment: can you include your imports? - it will speed up analyzing the problem

Comment: @ErikR added imports

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation can tell you](https://s3.amazonaws.com/haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.17/shakespeare-2.0.8.2/Text-Julius.html#t:ToJavascript), the `ToJavascript` class only has instances of

- `Bool`
- `RawJavaScript`
- and [JSON `Value`s](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.11.2.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Value). These are what you want to use.

```
import Data.Aeson    

test = renderJavascript $ jsCode (⊥)
  where
    yval = Number 3
    jsCode = [js|
      var y = #{yval};
      |]
```

...or, if `yint = 3 :: Int` is given, `yval = Number $ fromIntegral yint`. Both uses the fact that the `Number` constructor uses a `Num` type (so you can use numerical literals as well as standard conversion functions), namely [`Scientific`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scientific-0.3.4.6/docs/Data-Scientific.html#t:Scientific).

Why, if there's a class `ToJavascript` anyway, they don't also offer at least an instance for `Int`, I have no idea.